# Wait one minute before running the function?

Tags: javascript

I want to give it a one minute wait before it runs.

```
    function hideWidget() {
        selWidget.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    document.querySelector('.fkr').addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
        hideWidget()
    }, false);
```

I tried a few referent ways without success, thank you in advance. eg.. `setTimeout(hideWidget, 200);`

Comment: Is it important that it's exactly 1 minute, or can it be approximate?

Comment: It can be anything, i will adjust it accordingly. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right path. It looks like you just needed to figure out how to set the length of the timeout. The second parameter is what is determining how long to wait before executing the function and it is measured in miliseconds. 1 milisecond is equal to 0.001 seconds, so in order to get 60 seconds you need to multiply 1 by 1000 by 60. So the code would look like

```
setTimeout(hideWidget, 60000);
```

Comment: Thank you.
I have it like that, in some functions it works, however the code on top of this page (the one that im having trouble with) is not working.